# onmouseover effect not working in asp.net imagebutton

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

im trying to create a onmouseover effect in my imagebutton which is similar to this css hover effect code below.

```
.button:hover
{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Originally I have a div tag with a class that is equals to the css hover effect and inside it is my imagebutton. When im hovering the imagebutton, the background-color blue is underneath the image. Here is the image below:[image]

As you can see from the picture above, As i hover the Ibanez logo, it only creates a blue line at the left,right and bottom border. So i decided to try to implement the hover effect directly in imagebutton, which is surprisingly difficult than the normal css approach. I've read online that you should add onmouseover in code-behind because imagebutton doesn't normally have it and should be placed in the Page_Load.

In my case, i cannot do that because my imagebutton is inside a repeater which cannot access the image button's id directly. So i ended up making an OnItemCommand to access the imagebutton. Well unfortunately my solution did not work and no hover is happening in my imagebutton. Please help me on solving this one.

Here is the aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language='C#' MasterPageFile='~/MasterPage.master' 
 AutoEventWireup='true' CodeFile='GuitarBrands.aspx.cs' 
 Inherits='Pages_GuitarBrands' %>

 <asp:Content ID='Content1' ContentPlaceHolderID='ContentPlaceHolder1' 
 Runat='Server'>

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="getImageHover">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="one-third">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="brandImage" OnClick="Repeater1_OnClick"  
  height="250px" width="300px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") 
  %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' 
  onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='blue';" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>

 </asp:Content>
```

Here is the aspx.cs code:

```
public partial class Pages_GuitarBrands : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public List<guitarBrand> brandList { get; set; }
private string brandType = "Guitar";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        DataSet ds = GetData();
        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }

}


protected void getImageHover(object sender,RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton image = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;
    image.Attributes.Add("onmouseover","this.style.backgroundColor=\"blue\"");
}

private DataSet GetData()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["brandsConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from guitarBrands", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }

}

protected void Repeater1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ImageButton image = (ImageButton)sender;
    if (image != null) {
        int id = int.Parse(image.CommandArgument);
        string brandName = ConnectionClassBrands.GetBrandById(id);
        ConnectionClassGuitarItems.guitar = brandName;
        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/GuitarItems1.aspx");
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript to apply the styling instead of CSS classes and the [hover pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)?

Comment: Fyi..im really a beginner in this so providing a solution to this is highly appreciated

Comment: I have searched online for answers but there isn't any. I wonder if anyone can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void getImageHover(object sender,RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton image = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;
    image.Attributes.Add("class","button");
}
```

While in CSS, use:

```
<style>
.button
{
    background-color: none;
} 
.button:hover
{
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in OnItemCommand event of Repeater. Hope this may help

```
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    { 
ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("brandImage");
 image.Attributes.Add("onmouseover","this.style.backgroundColor=\"blue\"");
}
```